# Date format - Numbers after Z (Zulu time)

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to parse this date: 2018-03-14T09:45:00**Z283** UTC

Pretty straight forward except for the bold part. I know that Z stands for Zulu time, but what is the number after the Z?

Comment: number of milliseconds.

Comment: shouldn't those numbers be before Z? to match typical pattern of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`

Comment: `Z` does **not** stand for Zulu, it stands for UTC!

Comment: @T.G if the date was supposed to be ISO8601 compliant, yes it should.

Comment: @OlegSklyar quote from wikipedia's page on ISO8601 : `The Z suffix in the ISO 8601 time representation is sometimes referred to as "Zulu time"`. Then it goes on saying it's a source of confusion, so you're not wrong either.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks. i just found this https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-time-zone-handling/ and i think it clarifies this quite nicely

Comment: @Aaron LOL, did not know that :)

Comment: That is not standard, you should ask those who generates that date string why it looks this way.

Comment: @Aaron Ok thanks, to summarize, this is not formatted correctly, and if the 283 were before the Z it would be milliseconds?

Comment: so it looks like someone made mistake in formatter `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX` and it probably looks like `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.XXXSSS`

Comment: I think this was supposed to be ISO 8601, thanks everyone, would upvote if I could ...

Comment: @NinoNeuwirth yup, that's a good summary.